# Installing multiple nginx ingress controller instances in the same AKS cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, helm3

I have a brand new (so empty) AKS cluster. I want to install two instances of the nginx ingress controller, in different namespaces and with different ingress class, using helm.

I start with the first:

```
helm install ingress1 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace namespace1 --set controller.ingressClass=class1

NAME: ingress1
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Sep 24 20:46:28 2021
NAMESPACE: namespace1
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
The ingress-nginx controller has been installed.
It may take a few minutes for the LoadBalancer IP to be available.
```

All good

Now I go with the second:

```
helm install ingress2 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace namespace2 --set controller.ingressClass=class2

Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "ingress2": current value is "ingress1"; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "namespace2": current value is "namespace1"
```

What is the correct way to install multiple nginx ingress controller instances in the same cluster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you're setting the wrong values, thus the class name is `nginx` in both installs. Take a look at the template here: [controller-ingressclass](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/3ae09fd1fac381fce9f5066febf172a4a70c10a9/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-ingressclass.yaml#L13)

If you're using the official ingress-nginx Helm repository: `https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx` then try setting this instead: `controller.ingressClassResource.name=class1|class2` instead:

```sh
helm install ingress1 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace namespace1 --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=class1

helm install ingress2 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace namespace2 --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=class2
```

depending on your needs, you may also require to change the other values [of the ingressClassResource](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/3ae09fd1fac381fce9f5066febf172a4a70c10a9/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L98)

Comment: Brillant. The only documentation I could find is https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/#uninstalling-the-crds and it mentions controller.ingressClass and not controller.ingressClassResource

Comment: @FrancoTiveron Glad to help :) Another thing. ingress-nginx and nginx-ingress are two different ingress controllers that use nginx. The one you're using is maintained by the k8s open source community and it's helm chart is located here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx
The other one is maintained by NGINX inc. and is located here: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress

Comment: Thanks!
They changed "controller.ingressClass" -> "controller.ingressClassResource.name"